# Systemd print logs to external log file

Tags: 16.04, systemd, logging

I have the following Systemd service script to run a Spring boot application-

```
[Unit]
Description=Upstart for Security
After=network.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/security
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath java -Dspring.profiles.active=stage -jar /home/ubuntu/security/security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /home/ubuntu/security/security.log 2>&1
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=always
RestartSec=120s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**I save the script in the following location -**

```
 /etc/systemd/system
```

**I ran the following commands to run the systemd service script -**

```
1. sudo systemctl enable security.service -or- sudo systemctl daemon-reload
2. sudo systemctl status security.service 
3. sudo systemctl start security.service
```

**To check logs, I fire the command -**

```
journalctl -u security.service
```

and use `SHIFT+G` to scroll to eof

I am able to check the logs by the above steps, but I want them in an external file in location **/home/ubuntu/security** , as **security.log**
How can I achieve it? What change do I make in my systemd script?

Comment: This line `/home/ubuntu/security/security.log 2>&1` won't run as this is not a shell script as I have learnt, but for re-direct I haven seen such but still looking

Comment: yea, it worked with Upstart but no luck with systemd as far as custom  log file is concerned :'(

Answer (score 4):

systemd already provides a custom log for you by default in the systemd journal. It automatically redirects both STDIN and STDOUT there either as well as handling log file growth and rotation.

Just leave the log file redirection out of your `ExecStart=` line. To view the logs generated by your service, use `journalctl -u security`.

See `man journald.conf` for related configuration options and `man journalctl` for more options for viewing and querying the log data.

The docs in `man systemd.service` explain that the redirection syntax is not supported in the `ExecStart=` line:

> This syntax is intended to be very similar to shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions
>   described in the following paragraphs are understood. Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and
>   ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are
>   not supported.

Comment: My problem is, when we had an Upstart in place we were able to create a separate log file and when we faced any problems, we could download that log file locally and send to respective team. So how do we do that with Systemd ?

Comment: You can always export a copy of the log when needed with `journalctl -u security > /path/to/security.log`. Make sure in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` that you have `Storage=persistent` to make sure that logs are perserved between boots.